# Tailing only updated line of file

Tags: filesystem, tail

I want to tail only the updated line of the file not entire content

tail -F /path to file

displays all the line from the file. I need to display only the new lines added to the file
can anyone help me in this ?

Regards Chhaya

Answer (score 0):

`tail -F -n0 file.txt`

Man page about `-n`:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
          output lines starting with the Kth
```

Comment: i want to see only updated lines in the file for e.g if file has 10 lines tail -F shows me 10 lines on terminal now if 5 more  line are added i should be able to see only new 5 lines not all the 15 lines

Comment: Have you tried it? This is exactly what is does. n = 0, so it outputs 0 of the last lines.

Comment: i dont need 0 of the last line i need newly added line

Comment: What do you mean? This line does exactly want you need. It shows only the newly added lines. Have you tried it?

Comment: @OrangeTux what he wants in comment is impossible. He wants to erase the 10 lines added but see the next new 5 lines. Then when 2 lines are added he wants the 5 to disappear and see the 2 new ones. Not possible. Even when erasing the file the output is still on the screen and you can not do a clear in between :)

Comment: Aha, now all the comments make sense to me. Ty.

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma Even if this were possible, it'd not be useful. Files are (always?) written to sequentially. Hence, even if 5 new lines appeared in a file, you'd really have a single line added 5 times. If the previous lines were deleted, then the first 4 of these lines would also be deleted extremely quickly, and you'd only see the last one. The previous 4 would be displayed for microseconds, and never seen by the user.